# Syncing SharePoint 2013 to File Explorer when using Microsoft 365 Apps for Enterprise and not Microsoft Office professional

Tags: synchronization, sharepoint-2013, onedrive, microsoft365

I am an IT Intern tasked with designing an online SharePoint 2013 filing platform to replace local shared drive.

I have created the different department sites and currently awaiting migration. While training the users they requested that they be able to open the SharePoint folders on the file explorer like with shared drive instead of always using the browser and other inconveniences that come with it.

I understand that for us since we are using Microsoft 365 which doesn't install Groove.exe we are not able to sync the SharePoint folder to their file explorer. It was possible when using Microsoft Office Professional but since the head office issued a request to update all users, now that I have finished with the setting up of SharePoint 2013 sites all users are on Microsoft 365 and do not have the OneDrive for Business which made it possible in my tests while designing the platform and now I cannot find a way to map and/sync the SharePoint folder to every users' file explorer.

My question is, how can I sync SharePoint 2013 sites to the file explorer?

I tried to download the Groove.exe application expecting that the OneDrive for Business app would return but decided to conduct further searches to avoid installing applications that are no longer monitored by Microsoft on a work computer.

When syncing now it shows OneDrive and after accepting to sync with it, only the popup dialogue box disappears and nothing else.